# Positioning second leaflet tileLayer

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am working with leaflet at the moment and want to add a satellite image to the normal osm map tileLayer. So I managed to convert the image to tiles and setup leaflet to display the tiles.

Unfortunately the image then shows up at corner of the world. I know it is probably because that corner corresponds to the folder-numbers/grid of the tiles. However I need to the image to be in a very specific position. Is there any way I can tell leaflet where to show the custom tileLayer.

I realize that I can technically go and and rename to folders and images the the correct numbers of the area that I want it to be but that is very tedious and you have to do it manually which defeats our goal.

Thanks

Comment: If you have a single zoom level and your image is not too big, Tile Layer is really not appropriate. You should _georeference_ your image, then add it as an Image Overlay (iH8's answer)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `L.ImageOverlay`:

> Used to load and display a single image over specific bounds of the map.

```
var imageUrl = 'http://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/historical/newark_nj_1922.jpg',
    imageBounds = [[40.712216, -74.22655], [40.773941, -74.12544]];

L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(map);
```

Reference: http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#imageoverlay

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This was our first solution, but the images we got from our client is really large and when we tried to use the L.ImageOverlay it took too long for the image to show (if it did) and the page's speed was reduced significantly. The image is 130mb.

Comment: Then use a tool like e.g. [gdal2tiles](http://www.gdal.org/gdal2tiles.html) to split that image into EPSG:3895 tiles, and load that as a `L.TileLayer`. Or provide a WMTS service.

Comment: Thanks for recommendation. We found a similar tool for JavaScript, https://github.com/spacebetween/imageMapTiles.